Issues in Reading pdf in expo router when passing it from another Component
I want to read some pdf files through react-native-pdf library. I am passing the links of the pdf's to the pdf reader component which gives me an error.
from where I am passing the links
import { View, Text, StyleSheet,FlatList , Image, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'
import React,{useState}from 'react'
import { Link} from 'expo-router';

const Ninth = () => {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([
    {
      name: 'Mathsss',
      image: require('../../assets/images/1.jpg'),
            description: ' book 1.',
            num: 1,
             link: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/kankor-afg.appspot.com/o/school%20books%2F10%2F%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%BE%DB%8C%D9%88%D8%AA%D8%B1_%D8%B5%D9%86%D9%81_%D8%AF%D9%87%D9%85.pdf?alt=media&token=f446c85d-423c-4906-9c53-992dda2835b0'

          },
    {
      name: 'Chemistry',
      image: require('../../assets/images/2.jpg'),
      description: 'Tbook 2.',
      num: 2,
       url: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/kankor-afg.appspot.com/o/school%20books%2F12%2F%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%AE_%D8%B5%D9%86%D9%81_%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B2%D8%AF%D9%87%D9%85.pdf?alt=media&token=773991c1-2eae-45ae-8fcf-44b5aa7562c9'
    },
  ]);
 

   
  return (
      <View style={styles.container}> 
      <FlatList
      data={books}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      renderItem= {({ item }) => (
        <Link  
        key={item.num}
        
        href = { {
          pathname: '/BookTopTabs/detail/id',
          params: { link: item.link },
        }}
        asChild>
         <TouchableOpacity style={{padding:10, flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor:'#fff',margin: 8 , borderRadius:8, elevation:8,}}>
         
           <Image source={item.image} style={{ width: 70, height: 100, borderRadius:8, resizeMode:'cover' }} />
         
       <View style={{padding:7}}>
           <Text style={{fontSize:15, fontWeight:'bold'}}>{item.name}</Text>
           <Text>{item.description}</Text>
           </View>
          
          </TouchableOpacity>
        
          </Link>
         )}
        
     
      
    />
 
      </View>
  )
}

export default Ninth
const styles = StyleSheet.create({})

The component where I want to read
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import Pdf from 'react-native-pdf';
import { useLocalSearchParams } from 'expo-router'
import YoutubePlayer from "react-native-youtube-iframe";
import React, {useState, useCallback} from 'react'
import ReactNativeBlobUtil from 'react-native-blob-util'




const  Ap = () => {



   const {link} = useLocalSearchParams() ; 

   console.log(link)
  


  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);

    const onStateChange = useCallback((state) => {
      if (state === "ended") {
        setPlaying(false);
        Alert.alert("video has finished playing!");
      }
    }, []);
  
    const togglePlaying = useCallback(() => {
      setPlaying((prev) => !prev);
    }, []);
 
  return (
  
    <Pdf
      trustAllCerts={false}
        source={{ uri: link , cache: true}}   
      onLoadComplete={(numberOfPages, filePath) => {
        console.log(`Number of pages: ${numberOfPages}`);
      }}
      onPageChanged={(page, numberOfPages) => {
        console.log(`Current page: ${page}`);
      }}
      onError={(error) => {
        console.log("Error loading PDF:", error); // This is where you handle errors
      }}
      onPressLink={(uri) => {
        console.log(`Link pressed: ${uri}`);
      }}
      style={styles.pdf} />
  //  </View>

  );
}

export default Ap
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  pdf: {
    flex: 1,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
  }
});

note: in the console : console.log(link) it gives the exact link means its passing perfectly but when iam clicking on the book to open it it give an error which is given below. the termal:  LOG  https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/kankor-afg.appspot.com/o/school books/10/کامپیوتر_صنف_دهم.pdf?alt=media&token=f446c85d-423c-4906-9c53-992dda2835b0

LOG  Error loading PDF: [Error: cannot create document: File not in PDF format or corrupted.]

also check out this picture that where actually the error occurs: https://1drv.ms/i/c/5dff56b821ed00f8/EZhdM_etmgxFpszwfGLhF7UBkcpbWVA8yrCQ1WF6pYqRiA?e=M0S439
